# RLException: Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command

Tags: ros2, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the ros melodic, when i launch my launch file, i have this error.

My launch is it :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find robufast_base)/launch/robufast.urdf'" />

<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher"/>

<!--<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz"/>-->

<arg name="gui" default="true" />

<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />

<param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345333/rlexception:-invalid-%3Cparam%3E-tag:-cannot-load-command-parameter-%5Brobot_description%5D:-command/) by [merco.may-pay-afidu](https://answers.ros.org/users/52134/merco.may-pay-afidu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-02-28**:
robot_state_publisher needs a model of your robot (usually a [urdf](https://wiki.ros.org/urdf) file) and it expects its content to be available on the `robot_description` parameter.

You can see [q267328](https://answers.ros.org/question/267328/how-to-put-urdf-in-parameter-server/) for an example of how to set the `robot_description` parameter.

If your robot is described using Xacro files and not urdf you can use the following pattern instead:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py --inorder $(find pkg-name)/path/file.urdf.xacro" />
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-28**:
I believe there is actually a `robot_description` parameter being loaded.

It just wasn't visible due to incorrect formatting of the `.launch` file in the question text.

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-02-28**:
oh right, converting to comment then, thanks

@mercomay-pay-afidu can you provide the full console output that gets printed when you launch your launchfile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error is that the `<param>` is in the top-level scope of the launch file. In ROS 2, `<param>` tags must be contained inside of `<node>` tags. Try changing your launch script to look more like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher">
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find robufast_base)/launch/robufast.urdf'" />
</node>

<!--<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz"/>-->

<arg name="gui" default="true" />

<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />

<!-- You'll need to a figure what node is consuming this parameter and pass it directly to the node -->
<!--param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)"/-->

</launch>
```

The `robot_description` parameter should be passed directly to `robot_state_publisher`.
As my comment in the above code states, you'll also need to move the `use_gui` parameter inside of tags for the node that needs it.

**The above launch script will only work with the latest version of `robot_state_publisher` (ROS 2 Foxy or later).**
This is because it was changed to read the robot description from a parameter (like in ROS 1) in https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/pull/126.

For ROS 2 Eloquent, or older, you'll need to pass the robot description **file** as a **command line argument**. For example,

```
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher"
    args="$(find robufast_base)/launch/robufast.urdf'" />
</node>
```

With the caveat that `robufast.urdf` above has already been expanded by `xacro`.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2020-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1